# BASH: Process Substitution in a Variable

Tags: bash, process-substitution

What works is

```
vimdiff -c 'set diffopt+=iwhite' <(curl -sS '...') <(curl -sS '...')
```

Now I want to make a script that allows defining between two or four URLs and then generate the above command.

What I have for now:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=(-c 'set diffopt+=iwhite')
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  args+=(<(curl -sS "$1"))
  shift
done

vimdiff "${args[@]}"
```

When run with two URLs it results in `vimdiff` showing two tabs without content and with the same filename at the bottom, e.g. "/proc/20228/fd/63". In other words the process substitution doesn't seem to be applied and/or wrong as I'd at least expect to see two different file descriptors in the filenames.

I guess that the problem is either in the `args+=...` line or in the last line.

Comment: How are you calling your script? What arguments do you provide? You could also just loop `for i in "$@"; do ... done`. Completely up to you, but avoids the additional `shift` generally used in POSIX shells where you don't have arrays.

Comment: Your primary problem is `<(curl -sS "$1")` is expanded in the `args+=` argument and doesn't wait for the `vimdiff "${args[@]}"` command. Dump the `args` array before that command to check, e.g. `declare -p args` You should shoot for separating your command as `vimdiff "${args[@]}" <(curl -sS "$file1") <(curl -sS "$file2") ` to ensure process substitution does not occur earlier.

Comment: Process redirection is not executed when it is written inside quotes. Therefore `vimdiff` receives your `<curl ...` just as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick, and it is very close to your original proposal:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=(-c 'set diffopt+=iwhite')
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  exec {fdnum}< <(curl -sS "$1")
  args+=(/dev/fd/$fdnum)
  shift
done

vimdiff "${args[@]}"
```

So you'd first create all file descriptors via process substitution. By accessing their content via `/dev/fd`, you can easily collect them in an array and pass that to `vimdiff`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to use named pipes (FIFOs) instead of `<(...)` to create temporary files for `vimdiff`, in my example,`FIFOs` are created for each URL provided and the output of the `curl` command is redirected to the corresponding named pipe and the named pipe paths are then passed as arguments to `vimdiff`!

```
#!/bin/bash

args=(-c 'set diffopt+=iwhite')
fifo_files=()

cleanup() {
  rm -f "${fifo_files[@]}"
}

trap cleanup EXIT

while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  #creating a named pipe (FIFO) and add it to the array
  fifo=$(mktemp -u)
  mkfifo "$fifo"
  fifo_files+=("$fifo")

  #using curl to write the output to the named pipe
  curl -sS "$1" > "$fifo" &

  shift
done

#pass the named pipes as arguments to vimdiff
vimdiff "${args[@]}" "${fifo_files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code uses a recursive function to build a list of process substitutions:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

function vimdiff_urls
{
    local -r nurls=$1

    if (( nurls == 0 )); then
        vimdiff -c 'set diffopt+=iwhite' "${@:2}"
    else
        vimdiff_urls "$((nurls-1))" "${@:3}" <(curl -sS "$2")
    fi
}

vimdiff_urls "$#" "$@"
```

- The arguments to the function are a count of URLs, followed by a list of URLs, followed by a list of paths for process substitutions for `curl` fetching a URL.
- While any URLs remain, the function removes the first URL and adds a process substitution path for the URL to the end of the list of process substitution paths.
- This works because each process substitution path remains live until the function call where it was created completes.

Comment: didn't even know that we can use recursion in shell functions)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a better approach to me:

```
declare -p args=()
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  args+=("<(curl -sS ${1})")
  shift
done

bash -c "diff `declare -p args | grep -o -P '"<(.*?)"' | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -d '"'`"
```

This works :)

If you run your script using `set -x` at the beginning, you can see that when it arrives to executing the command, the two `<(xxx)` are inside a quote, thus interpreted as a string. This solves the issue. Clearly, using `bash -c` poses some security issues... however if the script is just for you, this should not be a big problem.

However, the script that uses the `fifo` posted in another answer seems cleaner :)

Comment: @sjngm :D :D let's say at least you don't waste your time trying something similar... :D (I am still investigating it... at some point I ll remove it)

Comment: Thanks for not letting that go. And yes, it looks confusing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider myself the Unix-/BASH-pro, so FIFO-pipes and the pipe-sequence are kind of beyond the solution. Don't get me wrong, it's nice to learn things.

Anyway, I just wanted to get my rather simple approach to work as it's basically just concatenating stuff and then running that, so here's my `eval`(-hell!!!):

```
args="vimdiff -c 'set diffopt+=iwhite'"
for url in "$@"; do
  args="$args <(curl -sS \"$url\")"
done

eval "$args"
```

It's not meant for production, just to check and compare.

Comment: For those confused by the '-hell!!!', see [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).